# Как импортировать модуль nodejs в typescript?

Tags: typescript

Хочу импортировать модуль `claster`.

Код:

```
import cluster from 'cluster';

console.log(cluster);
debugger;
```

**Пытаюсь получить его свойство... Не работает. Это и есть суть проблемы.**

```
cluster.isMaster
```

[Запускаю дебаггер, отключаю sourcemap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzANf.png)

И вижу такую картину - все методы / свойства лежат в объекте `cluster_1`. А в `console.log` стоит `cluster_1.default`. Свойства `default` там (`cluster_1`) вообще нет.

Как решить?

**Update 1:**

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "./dist/application",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130179/discussion-on-question-by-lasna1----nodejs--typescript).

Answer (score 0):

Предположу что Вы пишите на Node
Ответом на Ваш вопрос будет эта статья:
https://habr.com/ru/post/477168/

Собственно в основном файле Вы хотите использовать ES6 import.
Для этого надо либо :
включить в tsconfig type: "module"

Либо дать Вашему файлу расширение mjs, claster должен воспириниматься как common js - но на всякий случай можно дать ему расширение cjs

Comment: Попробовал. https://i.imgur.com/jDwJMOC.png Ничего не изменилось, вероятно проблема не в этом, так-как вообще импорты работают. Проблема только с `cluster`. Уже решил "костылем" https://i.imgur.com/zTdQuzr.png Но работает...